# Google Maps API 3 - Disable if Mobile

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Looking to disable the Google Map when browsed on a mobile device. Currently running CSS to hide the div if the browser window is 600px or below.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .mapCanvas {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

How can you disable the JS from querying the Google Maps API if the browser is 600px or smaller?

So that it won't query the API server when the map isn't even displayed.

```
<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };

        // Display a map on the web page
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(50);

        // Multiple markers location, latitude, and longitude
        var markers = [ <?php echo $js_markers; ?>

        ];

        // Info window content
        var infoWindowContent = [ <?php echo $js_content; ?>

        ];

        // Add multiple markers to map
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

        // Place each marker on the map  
        for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0]
            });

            // Add info window to marker    
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            // Center the map to fit all markers on the screen
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }

        // Set zoom level
        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
            this.setZoom(7);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });

    }
// Load initialize function
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=???&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the google maps API JS file if its mobile

Something like

```
if (typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined') { ... }
```